# if statement seemingly being ignored in for loop

Tags: python

noobie having trouble with if statements within a for loop

def abilityBuy():

```
totalPoints = 28 

abilities = {
    "Str":0,
    "Con":0,
    "Dex":0,
    "Int":0,
    "Wis":0,
    "Cha":0 
    }

for i,v in abilities.items():
    print "You have %s points." % totalPoints
    text = "Enter stat for %s: " % i
    stat = raw_input(text)
    if stat == 18: 
        totalPoints = totalPoints - 16 
    elif stat == 17:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 13
    elif stat == 16:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 10 
    elif stat == 15:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 8 
    elif stat == 14:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 6 
    elif stat == 13:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 5 
    elif stat == 12:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 4 
    elif stat == 11:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 3 
    elif stat == 10:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 2 
    elif stat == 9:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 1 
    elif stat == 8:
            totalPoints = totalPoints - 0

    abilities[i] = stat 

print abilities
```

abilityBuy()

when ran it suppose to deduce the number of points required for a stat number
example: if stat is equal to 18
reduce totalPoints by 16
this will give the totalpoints the remainder of 12 points but when ran the if statement is seemingly ignored and jumps passed them, adds to the dictionary and loops around and says totalPoints still equal to 28

i don't know if it is indentation  that is causing the issue or something else, also i have other for loops with if statements inside and they work how they are suppose to, yet this one doesn't seem to do what i am asking to

open to any suggestions

thanks

Lyncius

Comment: `print(stat)` will show you the problem.

Comment: hark! its a string, it needs to be converted to an integer

Comment: @Lyncius yup - you might also want to put some checking that they have some points left... at the moment you can just keep entering 18 for everything :)

Comment: yup that is my next challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `stat = raw_input` is returning a str value. stat is a str, and in your if statements your trying to compare it to an integer. `str == int` never works out. Either cast stat to an int, or compare it to str like...

```
stat = int(stat)
```

or

```
if stat == "18":
```

both will work out

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). It returns a string, and you're just comparing it to ints.

```
stat = int(raw_input(text))
```

would solve that part.

Comment: Why exactly would the OP want to consider not using `raw_input`..?. In 2.x it's the canonical way to get input from stdin...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy You're absolutely right, thanks! I did erase this before seeing your comment, I must say, but thanks notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind: `raw_input()` returns a string, but your if statements compare stat to integers so none of them will evaluate to true.
A simple solution is to convert it: `int(stat)`, but you will want to add a check for when users input non-numbers or values beyond what you test (ie, if a user inputs 19 or 'a').

Answer (score 0):

changed:

from
stat = raw_input(text)

to
stat = int(raw_inpur(text))

problem solved